# Case insensitive Dictionary in Swift

Tags: swift, swift2

Given a `Dictionary` whose `Key` is of type `String`, is there a way to access the value in a case-insensitive manner? For example:

```
let dict = [
    "name": "John",
    "location": "Chicago"
]
```

Is there a way to call `dict["NAME"], dict["nAmE"]`, etc. and stil get `"John"`?

Answer (score 15):

A cleaner approach, swift 4:

```
extension Dictionary where Key == String {

    subscript(caseInsensitive key: Key) -> Value? {
        get {
            if let k = keys.first(where: { $0.caseInsensitiveCompare(key) == .orderedSame }) {
                return self[k]
            }
            return nil
        }
        set {
            if let k = keys.first(where: { $0.caseInsensitiveCompare(key) == .orderedSame }) {
                self[k] = newValue
            } else {
                self[key] = newValue
            }
        }
    }

}

// Usage:
var dict = ["name": "John"]
dict[caseInsensitive: "NAME"] = "David" // overwrites "name" value
print(dict[caseInsensitive: "name"]!) // outputs "David"
```

Comment: Great answer, this adds flexibility to Dictionary without changing anything

Comment: This is a good answer. It's worth noting though that you can add keys in a case-insensitive manner, so you could create `var dict = ["name": "John", "NAME": "David"]` and the results of the case-insensitive lookup would become unpredictable.

Comment: Also complexity goes up from O(1) to O(n). Could as well use an array of key values then. The solution below solves this better.

Answer (score 8):

Swift support multiple subscripting so you can take advantage of that to define a case-insensitve accessor:

```
extension Dictionary where Key : StringLiteralConvertible {
    subscript(ci key : Key) -> Value? {
        get {
            let searchKey = String(key).lowercaseString
            for k in self.keys {
                let lowerK = String(k).lowercaseString
                if searchKey == lowerK {
                    return self[k]
                }
            }
            return nil
        }
    }
}

// Usage:
let dict = [
    "name": "John",
    "location": "Chicago",
]

print(dict[ci: "NAME"])      // John
print(dict[ci: "lOcAtIoN"])  // Chicago
```

This extension is limited to `Dictionary` whose `Key` is of type `String` (as lowercase is meaningless with other data types). However, Swift will complain about constraining a generic type to a `struct`. The protocol that is closest to `String` is `StringLiteralConvertible`.

Note that if you have 2 keys whose lowercase forms are identical, there's no guarantee which one you will get back:

```
let dict = [
    "name": "John",
    "NAME": "David",
]

print(dict[ci: "name"])   // no guarantee that you will get David or John.
```

Comment: like in real world keys should be identical. you could not deal with typos, you should fix them.

Comment: +1 to @vikingosegundo comment. Why do you need this? Why not just store all keys in lowercase for example (if case concerns you later). Looks like a decent solution to a problem that shouldn't be such :D

Comment: I had to use it in a recent project. The Dictionary was converted from JSON and I take an input, return the value, regardless of the case for the key. I couldn't convert all keys to lowercase either because I had to post it back to another webservice. For more context, search for "case insensitive dictionary" and you will find questions in almost every language that has dictionary.

Comment: Normalize the keys to something sense full like lowercase during the deserialization of JSON.

Answer (score 7):

The existing answers are fine, but the time complexity of lookups/insertions with those strategies deteriorates from O(1) to O(N) (where N is the number of objects in the dictionary).

To retain O(1) you may want to consider the following approach:

```
/// Wrapper around String which uses case-insensitive implementations for Hashable
public struct CaseInsensitiveString: Hashable, LosslessStringConvertible, ExpressibleByStringLiteral {
    public typealias StringLiteralType = String

    private let value: String
    private let caseInsensitiveValue: String

    public init(stringLiteral: String) {
        self.value = stringLiteral
        self.caseInsensitiveValue = stringLiteral.lowercased()
    }

    public init?(_ description: String) {
        self.init(stringLiteral: description)
    }

    public var hashValue: Int {
        return self.caseInsensitiveValue.hashValue
    }

    public static func == (lhs: CaseInsensitiveString, rhs: CaseInsensitiveString) -> Bool {
        return lhs.caseInsensitiveValue == rhs.caseInsensitiveValue
    }

    public var description: String {
        return value
    }
}

var dict = [CaseInsensitiveString: String]()
dict["name"] = "John"
dict["NAME"] = "David" // overwrites "name" value
print(dict["name"]!) // outputs "David"
```

Comment: Doubling your key storage seems a high cost.

Answer (score 4):

can use `Collection's first(where:)` to find first lowercased match from all keys mapped lowercased, then return the value from this result.

```swift
extension Dictionary where Key == String {
    func valueForKeyInsensitive<T>(key: Key) -> T? {
        let foundKey = self.keys.first { $0.compare(key, options: .caseInsensitive) == .orderedSame } ?? key
        return self[foundKey] as? T
    }
}
```

`first(where:)` is a much efficient way to filter or iterate over the large collection

reference:

- https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/anybidirectionalcollection/2906322-first#
- https://github.com/realm/SwiftLint/blob/master/Rules.md#first-where

Answer (score 1):

This should do the job with O(1) while also not allowing to add the same string with different casing (e.g. if you first insert Def it is not replaced by DEF). It also works for Substring if necessary. Note, that this solution is more memory effective, but comes at the cost at recomputing the string transformation and hash on every lookup of a string. If you need to look-up the same value frequently it might be worth to have an implementation which caches the hashValue.

```
struct CaseInsensitiveString<T: StringProtocol>: Hashable, Equatable, CustomStringConvertible {
    var string: T

    init(_ string: T) {
        self.string = string
    }

    var description: String { get {
        return string.description
    }}

    var hashValue: Int { get {
        string.lowercased().hashValue
    } }

    func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
        hasher.combine(hashValue)
    }

    static func == (lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Bool {
        return lhs.string.compare(rhs.string, options: .caseInsensitive) == .orderedSame
    }
}

typealias SubstringCI = CaseInsensitiveString<String>

var codeMap = [SubstringCI: Int]()
let test = "Abc Def Ghi"
let testsub = test[test.firstIndex(of: "D")!...test.lastIndex(of: "f")!]
codeMap[SubstringCI(String(testsub))] = 1
print(codeMap.keys, codeMap[SubstringCI("Def")]!, codeMap[SubstringCI("def")]!)
codeMap[SubstringCI("DEF")] = 1
print(codeMap.keys, codeMap[SubstringCI("Def")]!, codeMap[SubstringCI("def")]!)
```