# How to initialize a case insensitive dictionary using Swift?

Tags: swift, sorting, dictionary

My problem is that this code is case-sensitive. If I have "Sam" and "sam", they will be sorted into different keys. Any way that I can think of doing this is by converting the string into all lowercase, but I want it to stay as normal while being sorted without case-sensitivity:

---

```
var dict: [String: [String]] = [:]
for string in array {
    if (dict[string] != nil) {
        dict[string]?.append(string)
    }
    else {
        dict[string] = [string]
    }
}
```

---

As it is right now my code would result in:

```
["Sam": ["Sam"], "sam", ["sam"]]
```

Instead of what I want:

```
["Sam": ["Sam", "sam"]]
```

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Case insensitive Dictionary in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33182260/case-insensitive-dictionary-in-swift)

Comment: Not necessarily. My problem is with sorting, not getting.

Comment: Dictionaries aren't sortable...

Comment: No, I mean sorting an array into a dictionary.

Comment: I'm not using a built-in function. If you look, I'm checking if the string already has a key attributed to it. If yes, then I append it. If no, then I create a new key for the string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `reduce(into:)` method and assign each element capitalized to the result:

```
let array = ["Sam", "sam", "SAM"]
let dict: [String: [String]] = array.reduce(into: [:]) {
    $0[$1.capitalized, default: []].append($1)
}

print(dict)  // ["Sam": ["Sam", "sam", "SAM"]]
```

Comment: Works great - Even with two words in the string!

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to have case insensitive keys and case sensitive values, from given array, the shortest solution could be something like this:

```
var dict: [String: [String]] = [:]
array.forEach { dict[$0.lowercased(), default: []] += [$0]  }
```

Comment: using map here and discarding the result is totally pointless. The resulting type wouldn't have any use anyway. If going to this route what you would need is forEach instead of map

Comment: Btw when adding a collection of a single element to another collection you should use  [CollectionOfOne](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/collectionofone) `CollectionOfOne($0)` and [Dictionary has Key-based subscript with default value](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/dictionary/2894528-subscript) since Swift 4

Comment: You're totally right @LeoDabus! Thanks for pointing up this, i've edited my answer.

Comment: check the first link as well `+= CollectionOfOne($0)`